# How to receive data from node backend to react client using hooks?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I know that I need to use axios for this. But I don't have an idea how to make GET requests to my backend. I've done that with ejs. But with react, it looks much different to understand. I don't think the way I did that was correct, so I'm not going to include my code here. Please give me an example on this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` or `axios`.

Comment: I dont understand why people downvote my question. I watched a lot of videos but a lot of them are dealing with class components not hooks. There were not many resources to learn this concept. Please comment here if you're downvoting my question, so that I know what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: It's not me downvoting, but it's true that it's a veeery fundamental thing, available in pretty much every tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that hard to understand this concept. with axios you can do this,

This is what you need to have in your client side.

```
  const [mydata, setMydata] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/myapi'
    }).then(res => {
      setMydata(res.data);
    })

  })
```

This is the backend.

```
let details  = [10, 56, 78, 32]

app.get("/api/myapi", (req, res) => {
    res.json(details)
});
```

You can pass anything as the response. strings, variables, arrays, etc.